# Removing elements from an array and avoiding crashes in javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

So i have been working hard at a game using HTML5 and JavaScript. I am trying to make a space invaders styled game and as a result i have an array of enemies. I have separate functions dedicated to creating the array of enemies, drawing them to screen, moving the enemies and finally removing them.
 the removal of enemies however is causing an issue. This is my logic
if an enemies health is less than or equal to 0, delete the enemy from the array and shrink the arrays length by 1. Now logic would dictate that this can be a calamity, if you start shooting and killing enemies from the start of the array, as the arrays length will be reduced and this is exactly my problem, so low and behold my code.

```
function hostile(x, y) {
    this.speed = 1;
    this.health = 100;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = 32;
    this.width = 32;
    this.isDead = false;
    this.direction = 0;
    this.deadCount = 0;
    this.firing = false;
    //this.moving = true;
    this.move = function () {

        if (this.isDead === false && gameStart === true) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
            if (this.x > canvas.width - 64) {

                this.y += 10;
                this.direction = 0;
            }
            if (this.x < 0) {
                this.y += 10;

            }

            if (this.direction === 1) {
                this.x += this.speed;
            } else {
                this.x -= this.speed;

            }

            if (this.x < 0) {
                this.direction = 1;
            }

            if (this.y > 420) {
                this.x = 600;
            }
        }

    };

    this.draw = function () {

        context.drawImage(sprite, 0, 480, 65, 68, this.x, this.y, 65, 65);
    };
    this.reset = function () {
        context.clearRect(this.x, this.y, 65, 65);
        this.x = 20;
        this.y = 20;
        this.health = 100;
    };
};
var enemylist = [];

function createEnemies() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        enemylist.push(new hostile(75 * i, 20));

    }
};

function deleteEnemy(a) {
    enemylist.splice(a);
    enemyBulletList.splice(a);

    //enemylist.length  = enemylist.length-1;
    //enemyBulletList.length = enemyBulletList.length - 1;
};

createEnemies();

function moveEnemies() {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemylist.length; i++) {
        if (enemylist[i].isDead === false && gameStart === true) {

            if (enemylist[i].x > canvas.width - 64) {

                enemylist[i].y += 10;
                enemylist[i].direction = 0;
            }
            if (enemylist[i].x < 0) {
                enemylist[i].y += 10;

            }

            if (enemylist[i].direction === 1) {
                enemylist[i].x += enemylist[i].speed;
            } else {
                enemylist[i].x -= enemylist[i].speed;

            }

            if (enemylist[i].x < 0) {
                enemylist[i].direction = 1;
            }

            if (enemylist[i].y > 420) {
                enemylist[i].x = 600;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So to explain my problem, i can shoot and kill enemies from the array, this will also remove them from the screen. However if i shoot an enemy from the start of the array i cause all the enemies to cleared off the screen and the game to crash. If you need more information, feel free to ask.

By request, i have submitted more code relating to my question. The code above includes the hostile function and other functions associated directly with it.

EDIT: Vitim.us had offered a very useful tip regarding my question, he suggested to create a flag of some sort (var dead = false/true etc.) and once the value is changed the specific instance can simply be removed from the screen away from the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this in various ways

You can implement a method to hostile to remove itself from screen,

To this each instance should keep a reference to itself on screen, it can be a direct reference to DOM or it can be a property like `hostile.entitieId` that correlate to the onscreen object.

When `hostile.health<=0` you flag `hostile.isDead = true;` and automatically call a method to remove it from screen, than notify other method to finally delete the instance from your `enemyList[]`

You can either check this on the game tick or you can build it in a event dispatch fashion, using getter and setter for the health property.

```
this.setHeath = function(value){
   //set entity heath

   if(health<=0){
       //remove itself from screen
       //notify other method to clear this instance from the enemyArray[]
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't manually update the array like that. `delete` is for removing named properties. If you want to remove elements from an `Array`, use `splice`:

```
function deleteEnemy(a) { // capitalized functions are usually reserved for constructors
    enemylist.splice(a);
    enemyBulletList.splice(a);  
}
```

Also, `var enemylist = [6]` doesn't do what you think it does. It creates an array with a single element, `[6]`. You should create an empty array and then `enemylist.push(new hostile(...))` to add them to the array.

This will avoid you having to manually set the length (which you should not ever have to do.)

Comment: Hi Mathletics, thanks for your advice. I have implemented your suggestions into my code, while the code advice you offered stops the game from crashing it does not allow me to do what i would like (remove 1 enemy from the array at a time) if i kill the 2nd element in the array, then the 2nd/3rd/4th etc get removed from the screen too. Additional assistance is appreciated and thank you thus far.

Comment: You're going to have to post more code for that. When you splice the array, it's going to shift all the indexes for items after the removed element. If your presentation is based on those indexes, you're going to have a problem.

Comment: if you have just a fixed number of entities you can just flag then as dead instead of removing then from array, or you will need to have to keep track of the indexes.

Comment: i have updated my original post with additional code as requested by Mathletics. Hopefully this will be what is needed to provide a picture of what is wrong or just how terrible my coding is. By the way that code was copied and pasted line by line, i did not omit any code from that, the code is also in a single js file called main.js. I understand that a lot of people recommend splitting up the content for readability and then use grunt to minify and compress all those js files into a single one, at the end of development. But when i started off this game i didn't do that.

Comment: I was goign to suggest the same thing that @Vitim.us did . . . rather than remove them from the array, mark them as "dead" or "alive" (you could do this with `true` and `false` values or even just 1s and 0s).  This way, you maintain the order and number of the aliens, but still have a key to indicate that they should be removed.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you already have the mechanism with `this.isDead` . . . just use that instead of deleting them.

Comment: Regarding Vitim.us and talemyn's replies, thanks it is useful. However i must ask this next question. I came from a Java background and i am curious how is garbage collection done, if i were to set an object (enemy) to dead = true, how will the garbage collector handle it, would it?

Comment: it wouldn't, it will remain in memory unless you delete then, javascript have reference counting, it will only release the memory when there's 0 references to a object, since you're holding it in a array you have at least 1 reference.

Comment: cool thats interesting, but can you set an instance to null as opposed to using delete or .splice(); ???

Comment: Yes, but it is not the same, delete remove the property key and its content, setting undefined or null the content is replaced but the property key will remain and it will be listed in a for-in loop.

Comment: Awesome, that is very useful information and by the way i have implemented your suggestions and it works like a charm.